# Wordpress: Register Repeater Field with RestAPI

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, jet-engine

I am trying to register a Custom Post Type within WordPress RestAPI. I have gotten most of it to work (the post itself and the fields), but I am stuck on getting the repeater field to register. Here is what I have so far.

Here is a screenshot of the repeater field:

[image]

This bit of code is in my theme folders within the **functions.php** file. I have taken out a bunch of fields to shorten the code as they are all strings and are working just like the given field "reservation-status".

```
add_action( 'init', 'booking_register_meta' );
function booking_register_meta(){

    //This bit registers my custom post type
    register_post_type(
        'reservations',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => _( 'Reservations' ),
                'singular_name' => _( 'Reservation' ),
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'show_in_rest' => true,
                'supports' => array(
                    'title',
                    'custom-fields',
                    'revisions',
                    )
                )
            );

            //this bit registers my regular field
            register_meta(
                'post',
                'reservation-status',
                array(
                    'single'       => true,
                    'type'         => 'string',
                    'default'      => '',
                    'show_in_rest' => true,
                    'object_subtype' => 'reservations'
                )
            );

            //this bit is suppose to register my repeater field
            register_post_meta(
                'post',
                'occupants',
                array(
                    'single'       => false,
                    'type'         => 'array',
                    'show_in_rest' => array(
                        'schema' => array(
                            'items' => array(
                                'type'       => 'string',
                                'properties' => array(
                                    'occupant-first-name'    => array(
                                        'type' => 'string',
                                    ),
                                    'occupant-last-name' => array(
                                        'type'   => 'string',
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                )
            );
}
```

I am using the documentation from here: [Wordpress: Modifying Responses](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#array-meta-type)

Here is my JSON output when I use postman.(The fields with no values are correct). Note: Occupants is missing under meta. This is a GET request and the occupants repeater field for this post has information input.

```json
[
    {
        "id": 88737,
        "date": "2023-10-11T03:47:52",
        "date_gmt": "2023-10-11T07:47:52",
        "guid": {
            "rendered": "https://example.com/reservations/myemailgmail-com/"
        },
        "modified": "2023-10-15T22:43:12",
        "modified_gmt": "2023-10-16T02:43:12",
        "slug": "myemailgmail-com",
        "status": "publish",
        "type": "reservations",
        "link": "https://example.com/reservations/myemailgmail-com/",
        "title": {
            "rendered": "myemail@gmail.com"
        },
        "content": {
            "rendered": "",
            "protected": false
        },
        "template": "",
        "meta": {
            "_jf_save_progress": "",
            "reservation-status": "Pending Reservation",
            "reservation-number": "",
            "confirmed-reservation-id": "",
            "check-in": "2023-10-11",
            "check-out": "2023-10-18",
            "resort": "Bay Lake Tower",
            "room": "Deluxe Studio",
            "view": "Standard View",
            "room-request": "",
            "renter-first-name": "John",
            "renter-last-name": "Doe",
            "renter-full-name": "John Doe",
            "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
            "phone": "11231231234",
            "address": "Platform 9 3/4",
            "state": "",
            "points": "",
            "price-per-point": "",
            "deposit": "",
            "deposit-status": "",
            "total": "",
            "total-with-fee": "",
            "balance-status": "",
            "balance": "",
            "balance-with-fee": "",
            "balance-due-date": "",
            "date-balance-paid": "",
            "paypal-fee": "",
            "payment-method": "",
            "travel-credit-number": "",
            "promo-code": "",
            "contract-status": "",
            "7-month-window": "",
            "11-month-window": "",
            "comments": ""
        },
        "_links": {
            "self": [
                {
                    "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/reservations/88737"
                }
            ],
            "collection": [
                {
                    "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/reservations"
                }
            ],
            "about": [
                {
                    "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/types/reservations"
                }
            ],
            "version-history": [
                {
                    "count": 1,
                    "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/reservations/88737/revisions"
                }
            ],
            "predecessor-version": [
                {
                    "id": 88739,
                    "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/reservations/88737/revisions/88739"
                }
            ],
            "wp:attachment": [
                {
                    "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=88737"
                }
            ],
            "curies": [
                {
                    "name": "wp",
                    "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
                    "templated": true
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

**UPDATE!!!!**
Per the first answer I have changed "posts" to "reservations". See code below:

```
register_post_meta(
    'reservations',
    'occupants',
    array(
        'single'       => false,
        'type'         => 'array',
        'show_in_rest' => array(
            'schema' => array(
                'items' => array(
                    'type'       => 'string',
                    'properties' => array(
                        'occupant-first-name'    => array(
                            'type' => 'string',
                        ),
                        'occupant-last-name' => array(
                            'type'   => 'string',
                        ),
                        
                        'occupant-full-name' => array(
                            'type'   => 'string',
                        ),
                        'occupant-age' => array(
                            'type'   => 'string',
                        ),
                        
                        'occupant-gender' => array(
                            'type'   => 'string',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )
    );
```

Now my JSON response is this (I see Occupants, but it shows as null and there should be data there):

```json
[
    {
        "id": 88737,
        "date": "2023-10-11T03:47:52",
        "date_gmt": "2023-10-11T07:47:52",
        "guid": {
            "rendered": "https://example.com/reservations/myemailgmail-com/"
        },
        "modified": "2023-10-15T22:43:12",
        "modified_gmt": "2023-10-16T02:43:12",
        "slug": "myemailgmail-com",
        "status": "publish",
        "type": "reservations",
        "link": "https://example.com/reservations/myemailgmail-com/",
        "title": {
            "rendered": "myemail@gmail.com"
        },
        "content": {
            "rendered": "",
            "protected": false
        },
        "template": "",
        "meta": {
            "_jf_save_progress": "",
            "reservation-status": "Pending Reservation",
            "reservation-number": "",
            "confirmed-reservation-id": "",
            "check-in": "2023-10-11",
            "check-out": "2023-10-18",
            "resort": "Bay Lake Tower",
            "room": "Deluxe Studio",
            "view": "Standard View",
            "room-request": "",
            "renter-first-name": "John",
            "renter-last-name": "Doe",
            "renter-full-name": "John Doe",
            "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
            "phone": "11231231234",
            "address": "Platform 9 3/4",
            "state": "",
            "occupants": [
                null
            ],
            "points": "",
            "price-per-point": "",
            "deposit": "",
            "deposit-status": "",
            "total": "",
            "total-with-fee": "",
            "balance-status": "",
            "balance": "",
            "balance-with-fee": "",
            "balance-due-date": "",
            "date-balance-paid": "",
            "paypal-fee": "",
            "payment-method": "",
            "travel-credit-number": "",
            "promo-code": "",
            "contract-status": "",
            "7-month-window": "",
            "11-month-window": "",
            "comments": ""
        },
        "_links": {
            "self": [
                {
                    "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/reservations/88737"
                }
            ],
            "collection": [
                {
                    "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/reservations"
                }
            ],
            "about": [
                {
                    "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/types/reservations"
                }
            ],
            "version-history": [
                {
                    "count": 1,
                    "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/reservations/88737/revisions"
                }
            ],
            "predecessor-version": [
                {
                    "id": 88739,
                    "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/reservations/88737/revisions/88739"
                }
            ],
            "wp:attachment": [
                {
                    "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=88737"
                }
            ],
            "curies": [
                {
                    "name": "wp",
                    "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
                    "templated": true
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `register_post_meta()` function, the first parameter should be the post type that the meta field will be registered for. Currently, you are adding the `occupants` field to the `post` post type.

From your code it looks like your custom post type is `reservations`, so you should be registering the `occupants` field for the `reservations` post type.

Something like:

```
register_post_meta(
                'reservations',
                'occupants',
                array(
                    'single'       => false,
                    'type'         => 'array',
                    'show_in_rest' => array(
                        'schema' => array(
                            'items' => array(
                                'type'       => 'string',
                                'properties' => array(
                                    'occupant-first-name'    => array(
                                        'type' => 'string',
                                    ),
                                    'occupant-last-name' => array(
                                        'type'   => 'string',
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                )
            );
```

Have a closer look at [register_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_meta/) on the WordPress documentation.

Also, it's good practice to name your custom post types in a singular form.

Comment: I tried the change and can now see "Occupants". However, the object shows as null. Since the fields within it are also meta fields that leads me to wonder if I have to "register_post_meta" within the occupants registration. Also, I am assuming I need to change my other register post metas to "reservations" as well and just remove the 'object_subtype'? As that is why they are working?

Comment: @BunsenHoneydew Everywhere where you want to register post meta for the "reservations" post type using the `register_post_meta` function you will have to change the targeted post type as mentioned in my answer, otherwise the meta won't be registered and thus won't be returned from your REST route.

Comment: Any idea why the object returns null? I have edited my post.